# btrfs check: "Couldn't open file system"

Tags: btrfs, fsck

When I run `btrfs check /dev/sda1`, it returns "`Couldn't open file system`," whether /dev/sda1 is mounted or not. Why?

(cf. [this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg38888.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal experience with BTRFS (fedora 20/21) is that sometimes you have to use an updated version of the tools.
For example, I am recovering my primary workstation right now, but the initrd / systemd console (cannot mount root file system) is not able to mount / check the filesystem. Using a LIVE fedora it works (and I am backing up / recovering the file system, thank you)